ERROR while running this file from root directory

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\a\RDP\RDP': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


This error is showing. Help me out, please!

The checkout step is missing in your workflow.

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#understanding-the-workflow-file.
